# Proving RBM similar to feedforward neural network with single latent layer

Tags: neural-networks, restricted-boltzmann-machine

In an examination, I came across a question where I was asked to prove that RBMs are similar to a feedforward neural network with a single layer.

I have an intuition that the structure is similar (Fully Connected) and that a single code/hidden layer is present in both, along with presence of activation functions.

However, I am unable to figure out how do I go about proving this mathematically. Please help me out.

Comment: similar in what way...

Comment: @shimao That an RBM can learn what a neural network can and vice-versa.

Comment: @Quark There are results stating these models as "universal approximators" (see [for RBMs](http://nicolas.le-roux.name/publications/LeRoux08_rbm.pdf) and [for single layer neural networks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem)). However these models are used to learn the same things. RBMs are  used to learn a discrete distribution while the classical feedworward networks learn a continuous function.